# Turn off DDC/CI for my Monitor

Tags: multi-monitor, monitors

I have 3 monitors. 2 are Dell the other is Asus.

When I turn off all 3 monitors, and then turn them back on in the morning, all the windows that were open on on the Asus monitor have been moved to one of the other monitors, meaning that the monitor is detected as removed completely.

They all use DP, so I believe I need to turn off `DisplayData Channel Command Interface`. This is turned off on my monitor, however the issue still occurs: [image]

I have a Nvidia Card so have access to X Server Settings App.

Comment: Instead of turning the monitor all the way off with the power button, just let it go to sleep.  The HDMI link itself requires active participation from the monitor to maintain so when you turn the monitor off, it is as if you have unplugged it.

Comment: I always believed that standby mode still uses 50% of the energy?! :) Also a small note, I'm using DisplayPorts

Comment: No; standby mode only consumes a few milliwatts.  About the same as leaving a USB charger plugged into the wall when it isn't charging anything.  In fact, when you turn the monitor "off" but it is still plugged in, it is still consuming about the same amount of power.